# Security Exception when sending sms using cordova in android 7.0

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to send sms from a device using sms manager by adding the corodova send sms plugin .This app works fine till android6.0 device it sends the sms also but when i tried to send sms from android7.0 it shows me the following security exception.Before sending sms it asks for the permission and i have given the permission also.

Exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
at com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo$Stub$Proxy.getGroupIdLevel1(IPhoneSubInfo.java:583)
at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getGroupIdLevel1(TelephonyManager.java:2163)
at android.telephony.SmsMessage.hasEmsSupport(SmsMessage.java:854)
at com.android.internal.telephony.SmsMessageBase.calcUnicodeEncodingDetails(SmsMessageBase.java:409)
at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.calculateLength(SmsMessage.java:796)
at android.telephony.SmsMessage.fragmentText(SmsMessage.java:354)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.divideMessage(SmsManager.java:450)
at com.cordova.plugins.sms.Sms.send(Sms.java:143)
at com.cordova.plugins.sms.Sms.access$400(Sms.java:22)
at com.cordova.plugins.sms.Sms$1.run(Sms.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Code to send sms:

```
  var smsdata = ' தேதி: ' + this.currentbilldate + ' பில் எண்: ' + this.save_details.vehicle_bill_no + ' எடுக்கப்பட்ட பொருட்களின் விவரங்கள்: ' + this.smselements.toString() + ', மொத்த பொருட்கள்: ' + totalcount + '';
    var farmermobileno = this.entry_details.farmer_mobile_no;
    this.sms.send(farmermobileno, smsdata).then((result) => {
      this.commonService.presentToast('Message sent successfully');
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Error in sending message', error);
      this.commonService.presentToast('Message Failed');
    });
```

Plugin Name:
    cordova-sms-plugin

Text sending in sms:

```
 var smsdata = 'உங்கள் கணக்கில் அன்று 23-8-17 அட்வான்ஸ் தொகை ₹500  வழங்கப்பட்டுள்ளது.இருப்பு ₹5000';
```

Comment: I was looking at this issue and guess you may not be using the latest version of the plugin as i could see a fix made in latest version of the plugin stating "fix(android): Don't check permissions for intents". Another possible reason could be the latest behaviour changes made in android 7.0 - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html

Answer (score 3):

Hope you can use below method for checking permissions.

> On Android, an extra function is exposed to know whether or not you
>   have the permission to send a SMS (Android Marshmallow permission).

```
var app = {
    checkSMSPermission: function() {
        var success = function (hasPermission) { 
            if (hasPermission) {
                sms.send(...);
            }
            else {
                // show a helpful message to explain why you need to require the permission to send a SMS
                // read http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#explain for more best practices
            }
        };
        var error = function (e) { alert('Something went wrong:' + e); };
        sms.hasPermission(success, error);
    }
};
```

You can see more details here on [**Git too**](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/87).

**Update:**

```
var smsdata = 'உங்கள் கணக்கில் அன்று 23-8-17 அட்வான்ஸ் தொகை' + '₹500' +  'வழங்கப்பட்டுள்ளது.இருப்பு'+ '₹5000';
```

Comment: it asks for permission and even it works fine in android6.0 but in android7.0 it asks for permission after that it gets closed automatically and i have tried to send a single text in a string it works fine even in android 7.0 but when i have some numbers in the strings it gets closed automatically without send only in android7.0 i have checked the text length and it is only 81 characters

Comment: Can you show the text which you try to send with a number?

Comment: Do you know which `number` part cause issue? It seems `3 number` parts on your text.

Comment: the second and the third one is making the issue

Comment: Can you try as on **Update** section above?